# Отключить прокрутку страницы после нажатия колесиком мыши)

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть таблица в ней много строчек, при клике на поле tr колесиком мыши я получаю значения атрибута data-id и по нему отправляю пользователя на некую ссылку в новой вкладке браузера, вроде все ок

```
let btnKeys = document.querySelectorAll('table.table.person_table tbody tr');
for (var i = 0; i < btnKeys.length; i++)
{
  btnKeys[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function(event)
  {
    if(event.which == 2)
    {
        window.open('/person/' + this.getAttribute('data-id'), '_blank');
    }
  });
}
```

Но хочу отметить что когда мы кликнули колесиком мыши курсор становиться будто активным и страница скролиться туда сюда за мышкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как от этого избавиться?) preventDefault не помогает)

Comment: Может попробовать эмулировать отжатие колесика(типа повтоный щелчек вызвать)?

Comment: @SwaD двойное срабатывание клика будет - говнокод, придется делать счетчик и проверять его значение

Answer (score 0):

Если повесить обработчик события с помощью `onmousedown` и `return false`, то это сработает. А почему - я не знаю) Если опытные коллеги подскажут - буду благодарен.

```js
document.querySelector('.block1').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
  if (event.which == 2)
    return false;
});

document.querySelector('.block2').onmousedown = function(event){
  if (event.which == 2)
    return false;
};
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.block {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  height: 500px;
}
.block1 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.block2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="block block1">Scroll on</div>
  <div class="block block2">Scroll off</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как я понимаю `mousedown` срабатывает в момент нажатия кнопки на мышке, а вот `mouseup` уже после, так что после того как событие сработало, предотвращать будет нечего. (Точно также как со `scroll`, событие срабатывает после прокрутки, так что мы его не можем предотвратить)

Answer (score 0):

Нормально `preventDefault()` помогает

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('mousedown',(event) => {
  if (event.buttons === 4) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let id = event.target.closest('tr').dataset.id;
    console.log(id);
    
    // window.open('url'+id,'_self')
    // или
    // window.location.href = 'url'+id
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id='1'><td>первый</td></tr>
    <tr data-id='2'><td>второй</td></tr>
    <tr data-id='3'><td>третий</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: window.open('/person/' + id, '_blank'); добавляю открытие ссылки, но в текущем скрипте открытие происходит в новой вкладке и эта станица становиться активной. Пытался использовать blur но не помогает

Comment: mousedown делает всегда активное нажатие, я так понял в фоне нельзя будет открыть ссылку, а mouseup уже как раз в фоне открывает.

Comment: @lidovsci вопрос был про то, что при нажатии на колёсико мыши появлялся скроллинг. Я дал вам рабочий вариант, чтобы и скролл не появлялся и id можно было получить. Вы сейчас задаёте вопрос относительно другой проблемы. Я обновил ответ, добавив в коде комментарии по поводу открытия ссылки на той же вкладке